# How to Romove SUEXEC from apache webserver?

Tags: php, linux, apache, suexec

As client requirement i need to remove the suexec from apache to remove vulnerabilties.

To do that i am using apachectl -V command on linux machine.

i am getting many variables with path of the file like

-D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/sbin/suexec"

From the documentation on apache.org

if i would remove or rename this suexec file from the above path and restart the server, suexec will be deactivated and the above variable won't be show the file.

I am doing the same but the reflection is not showing. please help me out this.

Comment: For reference : 

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html

PARA : ERRORS

Comment: Leave your client out of it. It is not relevant to the question. Just explain the problem.

Comment: Depending on what distribution you're using, the "right" way to do it may be to just uninstall a particular package.  Regardless, this is offtopic for SO since it's about server administration, not programming.

Comment: Yes sir i'll keep this in mind but i didnt specify the client :)

Need to remove the suexec from apache server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-D SUEXEC_BIN=…` text that you're seeing is an option that was specified when the web server was compiled. It doesn't mean that suexec is being used, and it can't be removed without recompiling the web server (which you **should not** do here).

Comment: Then how can we confirm that the suexec has removed from the apache.
Is there any way to make sure that it is removed?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to manual on how to disable or enable suexec: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html#enable

Comment: Yes i am following the same method...i have removed that file from the given path and restart the apache server and checked the apachectl -V command. It still showing the SUEXEC_BIN = 'usr/sbin/suexec' which i removed.